# At US Immigration if stamping done says until xyz date, does it mean leave the country by that date or reach home country by that date

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, passport-stamps

I am on visitors visa to USA from India .
At the immigration in USA , the stamping was done and on it was written "until mon 02 2019" (as I told the offficial my return ticket is on 25th february 2019) .
My doubt is does this mean I should reach India by 25th february or leave usa by 25th february..??

As per my return ticket, I’ll start from U.S on 25th february and reach India on 27th February .

Thank you for your time and patience .

Comment: Is there a digit(s) missing from the date in your question? As written, it’s ‘Mon February 2019’, which doesn’t make sense

Comment: Could you take a photo? "mon" or "mar"?

Comment: "mon" should be the actual month, so it's probably rather "until mar 02 2019" or something similar (6 months from date of arrival)?

Comment: HI new user.  You must leave the US on that date, before midnight.

Comment: And the US does not have exit immigration formalities, so they use the time of your departing flight.

Comment: @Fattie please make your comment an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps "mon" is an abbreviation for "month", making "02" February (the 2nd month of the year)? In which case the question would be "does *until* mean *until the end of the month* or *until the beginning of the month*?"

Comment: Why should the US care when you get to India?  Just because you are heading home after leaving doesn't mean that's the required course.  I've taken trips involving multiple countries that meant I didn't get home until **long** after the date we were expected to leave various countries along the way.

Comment: Agree with @LorenPechtel. The US immigration cares about people coming into and leaving their country. Why would they care about when people enter/leave other countries?

Comment: thank you for the prompt replies . to the ones who wanted me to clarify the exact text tht ws written , it is "mon 02 2019" (not mar..this is the exact way it was written) after going through your replies my understanding is it is safe to leave U.S on 25th feb. Thank you for taking time out to address the query .

Answer (score 75):

THe USA doesn't care where you are after leaving the US; they only care about how long you're in the US for.

So it's simply the date by which you must leave the US.

Comment: "You must leave the United States by 25 February 2018". - Does that mean you can spend the day of the 25th in the country, so long as I leave by `00:00:00 26 February 2018`, or do I have to be out by `00:00:01 25 February 2018` (aka just after midnight on the 25th)?

Comment: @BruceWayne You can spend the 25 Feb in the US

Comment: [according to this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/39690/77222), the visa period is understood to be "until and including" its whole last day. overstay would begin after midnight.

Comment: And if your flight was supposed to leave at 11pm and leaves two hours late, you are in trouble. Having zero room for error is reckless.

Comment: @gnasher729 but would immigrations know your plane left two hours late?  I don't recall people checking my passport stamps while boarding the plane, and flight information isn't stored on the passport.  It's a lot of work to record this information for every late plane.

Comment: @gnasher729 If that happens and you're still outside the plane by midnight, you should ask for a CBP officer (at least some are usually around) and explain the Situation, and politely ask them to make a record of it, so that it's noted that the late exit was more or less beyond your control. Or, if you already made it to the plane before midnight, but it leaves late, get a delay confirmation from the airline and email it to the CBP, and politely ask them to make a note of it

Comment: @Nelson It's electronically stored, through data transmitted by the airline

Comment: @gnasher729 In practice if you're already in Departures I can't see any problem with this. It's not like there are customs officials at the gate. _But_ I wholly agree you want to leave some margin for error. Coke's suggestion is a good one too, to help avoid getting tripped up by electronic automations that may land you in trouble on your next trip.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You haven't left just because you're in departures. The US doesn't do border control on exit

Comment: @Coke: Airside is arguably "you've left" in many respects. I don't know whether this is one of those respects when it comes to electronic checks on later re-entry, which -- if the US doesn't do border control on exit -- I suppose must be the only factor then. If the only data available to future border control officers is when your flight took off, not when you went airside, then I can see how this may be a practical problem. Though there _must_ already be safeties here, because it's not as if a long delay incurred after you're already airside is a rare occurrence.

Comment: It sounds like the date given was just February ("mon 02") 2019, with no day specified, so presumably the OP has three extra days' grace (through February 28). That should allow for *most* flight delays.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "If the only data available to future border control officers is when your flight took off, not when you went airside" Exactly, that's how it is

Comment: @Coke: Understood. This must be a common problem then as long delays aren't uncommon and passengers aren't always landside when they are incurred. Another reason not to worry too much about it in practice, IMO, though if it can be avoided obviously then so much the better...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The problem is that the revocation of VWP eligiblity or a valid visa happens on an automatic basis, and it will be visible by check-in staff next time the person tries flying to the US. Hence the CBP ***must immediately*** be notified in case of an overstay beyond the person's control, so they can manually fix the records or at least add notes to it

Comment: @Coke: Interesting. Seems like a bit of a flawed system.